# Find the perpendicular line to the line parallel to axis

Tags: linear-algebra

I see the solution but, can't explain mathematically.

Given the triangle ABC with the verticec A(3;1), B(-2;0), C(8;-8). Determinate the intersection point of the median AM and the line l if l perpendicular AM and C€l.

M is middle point on BC. 
M(3;-4)
The equation for AM is:

(x-x1)(y2-y1)-(x2-x1)(y-y1)=0

(x-3)(-4-1)-(3-3)(y-1)=0

AM:x=3

l: y=mx+b

y=0.x-8

l: y=-8

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do any further algebra. The line $AM$ ($x = 3$) and the line $\ell$ ($y = -8$) intersect at the point $(3, -8)$.